# About API route naming conventions

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm working on an API route naming study and I'm curious about software developers' opinions and best practices regarding an issue I've encountered.

Let's assume I'm going to create two routes:

```
1) GET: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks/:id 

This path, as you can predict, is intended for a function that retrieves the task object with the specified id.
```

```
2) GET: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/tasks/archived-count 

This path, on the other hand, is intended for a function that retrieves the count of archived tasks.
```

When a request is made to the second endpoint, the "archived-count" is mistakenly treated as an id, resulting in incorrect data being returned.

What should be the best practice solution to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

switch the order they are defined in, if you place /archived-count first, the request wont be treated as if its an id. only if your path is not /archived-count then the request will move on and then your /:id route will match that request.

```
1) app.get('/api/v1/tasks/archived-count', (req, res) => {});
2) app.get('/api/v1/tasks/:id', (req, res) => {});
```

Comment: Yes, I know this solution, but it doesn't feels like a good solution to me. It doesn't seem like the right solution to keep moving this up every time I add a new endpoint. Do you have any other suggestions?